# Parsing command line input filename to check the correctness of the content

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

Want to parse the filename from the command line and check its correctness, such as (1) total length, (2) expected extension, (3) '_' position, and other input values.

The sequence should be as follows:

```
$check.exe input_file  L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.dat
```

It should check if the output file (L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.dat) is typed as it should (not by the exact values, but by the type and length).

```
// Function to check if a string consists of digits
int isNumeric(const char *str) {
    while (*str) {
        if (!isdigit(*str)) {
        return 0;  // Not a digit
        }
        str++;
    }
    return 1;  // All characters are digits
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check if the correct number of command line arguments is  
    provided
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s inputfile outputfile\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

   // Extract the output file name from the command line arguments
   const char *outputFileName = argv[2];

   // Define the expected format
   char asciiChar1, numChar1, asciiChar2, numChar2, numChar3[5],      
   underscore1, numChar4[17], underscore2, numChar5[5],  
   numChar6[4], extension[4];

   int result = sscanf(outputFileName, 
   "%c%c%c%c%4[0-9]%c%16[0-9]%c%1[0-9]%3[0-9]_%3[0-9]%4[.dat]",
                    &asciiChar1, &numChar1, &asciiChar2, 
   &numChar2, numChar3, &underscore1, numChar4, &underscore2, 
   numChar5, numChar6, extension);

  // Debugging print statement
  printf("Debug: sscanf result: %d\n", result);

  printf("Debug: asciiChar1: %c\n", asciiChar1);
  printf("Debug: numChar1: %c\n", numChar1);
  printf("Debug: asciiChar2: %c\n", asciiChar2);
  printf("Debug: numChar2: %c\n", numChar2);
  printf("Debug: numChar3: %s\n", numChar3);
  printf("Debug: underscore1: %c\n", underscore1);
  printf("Debug: numChar4: %s\n", numChar4);
  printf("Debug: underscore2: %c\n", underscore2);
  printf("Debug: numChar5: %s\n", numChar5);
  printf("Debug: numChar6: %s\n", numChar6);
  printf("Debug: extension: %s\n", extension);

 // Check if the extracted values match the expected format
 if (result != 12 || !isalpha(asciiChar1) || !isdigit(numChar1) || 
    !isalpha(asciiChar2) || !isdigit(numChar2) ||
    strlen(numChar3) != 4 || !isNumeric(numChar3) ||    
    strlen(numChar4) != 16 || !isNumeric(numChar4) ||
    strlen(numChar5) != 4 || !isNumeric(numChar5) || 
    strlen(numChar6) != 3 || !isNumeric(numChar6) ||
    strlen(extension) != 3 || strcmp(extension, ".dat") != 0) {

    printf("Error: Output file format is incorrect.\n");
    return 1;
}

// If all checks pass, the output file format is correct
 printf("Output file format is correct.\n");

 return 0;
}
```

---

Command line input:

```
.\check.exe inputfile L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.dat
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
Debug: sscanf result: 9
...
Debug: numChar5: 0001
Debug: extension:
Error: Output file format is incorrect.
```

This is the output I am expecting:

```
Debug: extension:.dat
```

This part is not working. Other parts are OK. Want to check if the `extension` is `.dat` or not for the filename. If not it will print error msg and exit.

Comment: No, `numChar6` is correct. `numChar5` is the first zero, followed by `001` which is in `numChar6`. Read the filename you supplied as an example, and trace through the debug output manually to match. The only issue that is there is the last four digits of `numChar4` - your sample filename has `4029`, while your debug output uses `2026`.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistyping - the '4029' and '2026'. But you are correct, I am trying to get one set extra. So the '0' part of 'numChar6' is assigned to 'numChar5'.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] not a dump of entire project.  Formatting is important for readability (`main()` is incorrectly formatted).

Comment: Edited my initial post. Formatted and put the relevant part.

Comment: Good job on revising the question.  To be a program you are at least missing headers at this point.  As is you are also missing an argument is `sscanf()` (12 format parameters and 11 arguments).  You program calls `isalpha()` but you didn't included it.

Comment: @Fakir, If input was `"L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.datxxx"`, (extra junk at the end), should that pass or fail?

Comment: Fail. It might be .bin or something. But should be exactly the way it is. L to 0001 part might be slightly different. But their length and type should be the same. Also, the position of the '_'.

Comment: @Fakir Does the accepted answer pass or fail `"L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.datxxx"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you introduce some extra white space in the format string and matching arguments along these lines:

```
    int result = sscanf(outputFileName, 
        "%c%c"
        "%c%c"
        "%4[0-9]"
        "%c"
        "%16[0-9]"
        "%c" // underscore2
        "%1[0-9]"
        "%3[0-9]_%3[0-9]%4[.dat]",
        &asciiChar1, &numChar1,
        &asciiChar2, &numChar2,
        numChar3,
        &underscore1,
        numChar4,
        &underscore2,
        numChar5,
        numChar6,
        extension
    );
```

so we are good up to the 2nd underscore.  Then you expect a number (`char numChar5[5]`) but that doesn't match the size of the variable.  Then 3 more numbers (`char numChat6[4]`) which is ok.  Then a 3rd underscore which isn't in the input. 3 more numbers which has no matching argument.  "%4[.dat]" which result in a buffer overflow as the extensions variable is a `char extension[4]`.  Overall 12 format directives and 11 arguments which is undefined behavior.

You can simplify it by hard-coding your fixed strings:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isNumeric(const char *str) {
    for(; isdigit(*str); str++);
    return !*str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s inputfile outputfile\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    const char *outputFileName = argv[2];
    char asciiChar1, numChar1, asciiChar2, numChar2, numChar3[5], numChar4[17], numChar5[5], extension[4];
    int result = sscanf(outputFileName,
        "%c%c"
        "%c%c"
        "%4[0-9]"
        "_"
        "%16[0-9]"
        "_"
        "%4[0-9]"
        ".dat",
        &asciiChar1, &numChar1,
        &asciiChar2, &numChar2,
        numChar3,
        numChar4,
        numChar5
    );
    printf("Debug: sscanf result: %d\n", result);
    printf("Debug: asciiChar1: %c\n", asciiChar1);
    printf("Debug: numChar1: %c\n", numChar1);
    printf("Debug: asciiChar2: %c\n", asciiChar2);
    printf("Debug: numChar2: %c\n", numChar2);
    printf("Debug: numChar3: %s\n", numChar3);
    printf("Debug: numChar4: %s\n", numChar4);
    printf("Debug: numChar5: %s\n", numChar5);
    if (result != 7 || !isalpha(asciiChar1) || !isdigit(numChar1) ||
        !isalpha(asciiChar2) || !isdigit(numChar2) ||
        strlen(numChar3) != 4 || !isNumeric(numChar3) ||
        strlen(numChar4) != 16 || !isNumeric(numChar4) ||
        strlen(numChar5) != 4 || !isNumeric(numChar5)
    ) {

        printf("Error: Output file format is incorrect.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Output file format is correct.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

with example run:

```
./a.out  input_file L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.dat
Debug: sscanf result: 7
Debug: asciiChar1: L
Debug: numChar1: 2
Debug: asciiChar2: A
Debug: numChar2: 3
Debug: numChar3: 0000
Debug: numChar4: 0102051303042026
Debug: numChar5: 0001
Output file format is correct.
```

Another approach would be to just parse the file name `is_valid_format()` possible via a little interpreter `is_valid_format2()`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *alpha(const char *s) {
    if(!s) return NULL;
    if(!isalpha(*s)) return NULL;
    return s + 1;
}

const char *digits(const char *s, size_t n) {
    if(!s) return NULL;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(!isdigit(s[i])) return NULL;
    return s + n;
}
const char *str(const char *s, const char *s2) {
    if(!s) return NULL;
    size_t n = strlen(s2);
    if(strncmp(s, s2, n)) return NULL;
    return s + n;
}

int is_valid_filename(const char *s) {
    s = alpha(s);
    s = digits(s, 1);
    s = alpha(s);
    s = digits(s, 5);
    s = str(s, "_");
    s = digits(s, 16);
    s = str(s, "_");
    s = digits(s, 4);
    s = str(s, ".dat");
    return s && !*s;
}

int is_valid_filename2(const char *s) {
    struct {
        enum { ALPHA, DIGITS, STR } type;
        union {
            int n;
            const char *s;
        };
    } format[] = {
        { ALPHA },
        { DIGITS, .n = 1 },
        { ALPHA },
        { DIGITS, .n = 5 },
        { STR, .s = "_" },
        { DIGITS, .n = 16 },
        { STR, .s = "_" },
        { DIGITS, .n = 4 },
        { STR, .s = ".dat" },
    };
    size_t n = sizeof format / sizeof *format;
    for(size_t i = 0; s && i < n; i++) {
        switch(format[i].type) {
            case ALPHA:
                s = alpha(s);
                break;
            case DIGITS:
                s = digits(s, format[i].n);
                break;
            case STR:
                s = str(s, format[i].s);
                break;
        }
    }
    return s && !*s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s inputfile outputfile\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    char *result[] = { "invalid", "valid" };
    printf("%s\n", result[is_valid_filename(argv[2])]);
    printf("%s\n", result[is_valid_filename2(argv[2])]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Tested and both of them are working fine. I corrected the parts you have mentioned in your comments. But I did not put extra char (%c) and also if (result != ) value was wrong. I need to convert the numbers to binary after acquiring them. For that, your first solution would be better?

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark.  Not sure how to evaluate "better" for you.  You can expand the parser the return the binary values found.  In the interpreter I might make the `struct .. format` an argument  expand the struct with the binary values you want it converted to.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simplification:

- `"%[]"` to restrict valid input.  Save into a `char` array.
- `"%n"` to save scan offset and determine end of string success.
- Use string literal concatenation to show with greater clarity the complex format.
- Change name of `asciiChar1` to `alphaChar1` as code is looking for A-Z, a-z here.
- Do not attempt to print a string unless it scanning success was *first* determined.

Notice that *only* way for the scan length to be correct is for all `[]` strings to successfully scan to their maximum width and that the next character to scan is a *null character*.
This greatly simplifies testing.

```
  char alphaChar1[2], numChar1[2], alphaChar2[2], numChar2[2], //
  numChar3[5], numChar4[17], numChar5[5];
  /* numChar6[4] Apparently not in OP's sample fileanme */

  #define FMT_ALPHA "%1[A-Za-z]"
  #define FMT_DIGIT "%1[0-9]"
  #define FMT_EXT ".dat"
  char sample[] = "L2A30000_0102051303042026_0001.dat";
  #define FMT_N (sizeof sample - 1)

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(outputFileName, //
      FMT_ALPHA FMT_DIGIT FMT_ALPHA FMT_DIGIT
      "%4[0-9]" "_" "%16[0-9]" "_" "%4[0-9]" FMT_EXT "%n", //
      alphaChar1, numChar1, alphaChar2, numChar2, //
      numChar3, numChar4, numChar5, &n);

  // Only this test needed.
  if (n == FMT_N && outputFileName[FMT_N] == '\0') {
    // Success
    printf("Debug: alphaChar1: %c\n", alphaChar1[0]);
    printf("Debug: numChar1: %c\n", numChar1[0]);
    printf("Debug: alphaChar2: %c\n", alphaChar2[0]);    
    printf("Debug: numChar2: %c\n", numChar2[0]);
    printf("Debug: numChar3: %s\n", numChar3);
    printf("Debug: numChar4: %s\n", numChar4);
    printf("Debug: numChar5: %s\n", numChar5);
  } else {
    puts("Failure");
  }
```

Output

```
Debug: alphaChar1: L
Debug: numChar1: 2
Debug: alphaChar2: A
Debug: numChar2: 3
Debug: numChar3: 0000
Debug: numChar4: 0102051303042026
Debug: numChar5: 0001
```

Comment: Thank you. Tested it. Working as you said. Thanks to all of your suggestions, it will also help me learn too. Using C after many years. Forgot mostly.